# Data Transfer from Hive table to Teradata table

Tags: python, hadoop, pyspark, hive, teradata

I have a table (employee) in a Hive database (company) with a record count greater than 41 million. The table is partitioned on current_date column.

```
select count(*) from company.employee
```

The result of above query is Hive query editor is: 41,547,896.

Now the main task is to copy this data to a table (employee_td) in Teradata database (company_td).

Below is the code written in PySpark to transfer the data from Hive to Teradata.

```
# creating a dataframe
df = spark.sql("select * from company.employee")

# removing the duplicate records
df = df.distinct()

td_url = 'jdbc:teradata://*****/Database=company_td, LOGMECH=LDAP'

# writing the dataframe to Teradata
df.write.format('jdbc') \
        .option('url', td_url) \
        .option('user', db_user) \
        .option('password', password) \
        .option('dbtable', "employee_td") \
        .option('driver','com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver') \
        .mode('append').save()
```

When the above code was executed I am facing the following error with some records copied to Teradata table. The number of records getting varied from execution to execution:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o204.save.: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 75 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 75.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 97, *******.***.******.com, executor 39): 
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 16.10.00.05] [Error 1338] [SQLState HY000] A failure occurred while executing a PreparedStatement batch request. Details of the failure can be found in the exception chain that is accessible with getNextException.
```

As mentioned in the exception:

```
Details of the failure can be found in the exception chain that is accessible with getNextException
```

Can someone help me in raising a detailed exception chain for the above error.

Comment: Without the full exception chain it's difficult to know what the underlying problem really is. Most likely, either some column values are not compatible with the target data type or some constraint (e.g. index uniqueness) is being violated.

Comment: @Fred The above mentioned error info was getting repeated in the log file. Could you please help me in getting detailed information of the error. The data is getting loaded when limit was mentioned (1 million records saved successfully) in the Teradata saving statement. Unable to get where its getting wrong.

Comment: Can  you  use `sqoop export`?

Comment: Since the message was repeated, multiple "batches" of rows likely encountered errors and had rows bypassed, but remaining rows were loaded. See if there is a `company_td.employee_td_ERR_1` and/or `company_td.employee_td_ERR_2` table on the Teradata side. ERR_1 would log data type errors and ERR_2 would log constraint violations. See the [FastLoad Reference](https://docs.teradata.com/r/Teradata-FastLoad-Reference/June-2021/Using-Teradata-FastLoad/Handling-Teradata-FastLoad-Errors) for more information about how to interpret the data in these tables.

Comment: @Fred There are no such tables (```company_td.employee_td_ERR_1 and company_td.employee_td_ERR_2```) got created in Teradata.

Comment: My mistake. Those tables would only exist for TYPE=FASTLOAD and you are not doing that; besides, mode('append') is incompatible with FASTLOAD. I don't know of any way to get Spark to traverse the exception chain. I would look at query log (DBQL) on the Teradata side to see if there is any useful information about the error. DBQL should log one of the actual errors rather than the 1338 "see exception chain".

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing your

```
df.write...
```

to

```
df.coalesce(1).write...
```

because I suspect that Teradata might not support parallel writing.